# MySQL ORDER BY [custom SET field value]

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I hope there's a simple solution for this:

I have a table where each row has it's own status (`SET` type field). Statuses can be:

- offline
- available
- busy
- distance

I'd like to order as follows

- available
- busy
- distance
- offline

I thought a simple

```
ORDER BY `status` ASC
```

will do the trick (alphabetical order) but it gives me the following:

- offline
- available
- busy
- distance

How can is sort out this in the most simple way?

Thanks in advance,

fabrik

Comment: Why the close-vote? (reason isn't apply too)

Comment: Don't forget to accept the correct answer @fabrik ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thought I'd add another way to order by custom field values,

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(status, 'available,busy,distance,offline')
```

(If the given strings contain a quote simply escape it)

Answer (score 26):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(status,'offline','available','busy','distance')
```

see [Mysql order by specific ID values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322849/mysql-order-by-specific-id-values)

Answer (score 11):

You could also do something like this, if reordering the `SET` values in impractical:

```
... ORDER BY CASE `status` 
                WHEN 'available' THEN 1
                WHEN 'busy' THEN 2
                WHEN 'distance' THEN 3
                WHEN 'offline' THEN 4
             END
```

Comment: This is the simplest way I can think to do it.  Another alternative would be to create a table with your statuses that has an order column and inner join that table and order the rows by order specified to each status.

Answer (score -1):

Simpler than the solutions above:

```
ORDER BY CONCAT(status)
```

Answer (score -3):

Nevermind.

The trick is saving `SET` values at the right order.

Comment: I must disagree: controlled insertion order cannot be the solution. Queries must not rely on the order the rows are in the table, because they can change anytime for any reason. `ORDER BY` is the way to go, it's its job after all. I would rather find a way to achieve it using `order by` clause then to enhance software consistency.

Comment: @TechNyquist as you can see, I've accepted an answer relying on `ORDER BY`. I just left this comment here as a bad example. Btw thank you for your input ;)

Comment: ur welcome. I meant this comment just for pointing out that it's not the preferred way, just in case of some newbie reading this. ["Please, don't try this at home"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Try_This_at_Home).