# MySql order by specific ID values

Tags: mysql, sorting

Is it possible to sort in MySQL by "order by" using a predefined set of column values (`ID`) like `order by (ID=1,5,4,3)` so I would get records 1, 5, 4, 3 in that order out?

**UPDATE:** Why I need this...

I want my records to change sort randomly every 5 minutes. I have a cron task to update the table to put different, random sort order in it.

There is just one problem! PAGINATION.

I will have visitors who come to my page, and I will give them the first 20 results. They will wait 6 minutes, go to page 2 and have the wrong results as the sort order has already changed.

So I thought that if I put all the IDs into a session on page 2, we get the correct records even if the sorting had already changed.

Is there any other **better** way to do this?

Comment: Are you asking if there is there a way mysql can order in no particular order?

Comment: It sounds like either your data model is broken/incomplete (*where* does this order come from?) or alternatively you're abusing MySQL.

Answer (score 256, accepted):

You can use ORDER BY and FIELD function.
See http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/209784

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(ID,1,5,4,3)
```

It uses [Field()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function, Which "Returns the index (position) of str in the str1, str2, str3, ... list. Returns 0 if str is not found" according to the documentation. So actually you sort the result set by the return value of this function which is the index of the field value in the given set.

Comment: I cant seem to get this to work without also using: WHERE ID
IN ( 1,5,4,3 )

Comment: how would you use this with None values?

Answer (score 35):

You should be able to use `CASE` for this:

```
ORDER BY CASE id
  WHEN 1 THEN 1
  WHEN 5 THEN 2
  WHEN 4 THEN 3
  WHEN 3 THEN 4
  ELSE 5
END
```

Answer (score 26):

On the official documentation for mysql about [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html), someone has posted that you can use `FIELD` for this matter, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(id,1,5,4,3)
```

This is untested code that in theory should work.

Answer (score 16):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id='8' DESC, id='5' DESC, id='4' DESC, id='3' DESC
```

If I had 10 registries for example, this way the ID 1, 5, 4 and 3 will appears first, the others registries will appears next.

Normal exibition
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

With this way

8
5
4
3
1
2
6
7
9
10

Comment: The confusing part for me initially was that you need to add `DESC` for the custom ordering. But if you do, you get the desired result.

Comment: @ViBoNaCci a way to look at it is TRUE being 1, FALSE being 0, so by sorting in an ascending manner, you get FALSE first, then TRUE. So if you want your results sorted with rows that match your criteria first, you need `DESC`

Answer (score 6):

There's another way to solve this. Add a separate table, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `new_order` (
  `my_order` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `my_number` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`my_order`),
  UNIQUE KEY `my_number` (`my_number`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

This table will now be used to define your own order mechanism.

Add your values in there:

```
my_order | my_number
---------+----------
       1 |         1
       2 |         5
       3 |         4
       4 |         3
```

...and then modify your SQL statement while joining this new table.

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table AS T1
INNER JOIN new_order AS T2 on T1.id = T2.my_number
WHERE ....whatever...
ORDER BY T2.my_order;
```

This solution is slightly more complex than other solutions, but using this you don't have to change your `SELECT`-statement whenever your order criteriums change - just change the data in the order table.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to order a single id first in the result, use the id.

```
select id,name 
from products
order by case when id=5 then -1 else id end
```

If you need to start with a sequence of multiple ids, specify a collection, similar to what you would use with an `IN` statement.

```
select id,name 
from products
order by case when id in (30,20,10) then -1 else id end,id
```

Comment: Add some more description

Comment: if you want to use order by for only one id then use 1 st query and if you want for multiple ids then use 2nd query

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order a single id last in the result, use the order by the case. (Eg: you want "other" option in last and all city list show in alphabetical order.)

```sql
select id,city 
from city
order by case 
when id = 2 then city else -1 
end, city ASC
```

If i had 5 city for example, i want to show the city in alphabetical order with "other" option display last in the dropdown then we can use this query.
see example other are showing in my table at second id(id:2) so i am using "when id = 2" in above query.

record in DB table:

```
Bangalore - id:1
Other     - id:2
Mumbai    - id:3
Pune      - id:4
Ambala    - id:5
```

my output:

```
Ambala  
Bangalore  
Mumbai  
Pune
Other
```

Comment: Try to add some explanation to your code, it will make your answer more clear and understandable. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: if you want to use order by for only one id (Eg:you want "other" option in last and all city list show in alphabetical order.) so you can use this query. it's working for me.

Answer (score -5):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY (columnname,1,2) ASC OR DESC
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? This looks similar to the accepted answer, but I don't think that `ASC OR DESC` is proper syntax

Comment: @NicoHaase the difference between ASC and DESC is if you use asc then the ids you use in field function will come in end and if you use  DESC then ids in the field function will come first

Comment: @NicoHaase you can use either ASC or DESC with the query either one accroding to requirement

Comment: So you cannot use both in one query. Nico was I think suggesting you made your answer syntactically correct. I am pretty sure he is familiar with what ASD and DESC actually mean :)

Comment: This makes no sense and will definitely not work.  You need to use the `FIELD` function, which is identical to the accepted answer from 8 years prior.