# ORDER BY proirity with specific value

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a column named **role** and values are as follow:

```
Scientific staff
PostDocs
Supporting staff
PNUT
Visiting researchers
Secretary
Ph.D. students
Students
Other
```

I want to use `ORDER BY` in such a way that **Scientific staff** comes first. At the moment when I do a query like this, the fields which are **Ph.D. students** will be returned first (Well because at the moment no row in database has a field with **Other** in it). Is there a way to achive this using `mysql` only or should I modify the returned values manually? If so, can you please tell me how?

```
SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY role
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql order by specific ID values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322849/mysql-order-by-specific-id-values)

Comment: You can `ORDER BY role ASC` or `ORDER BY role DESC`. Anything else would require a (numeric?) position column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without an additional table and join, just do:

```
SELECT * FROM members 
ORDER BY
  CASE role
     WHEN 'Scientific staff' THEN 1
     WHEN 'PostDocs'         THEN 2
     WHEN 'Supporting staff' THEN 5
     WHEN 'PNUT'             THEN 6
     WHEN 'Visiting researchers' THEN 4
     WHEN 'Secretary'        THEN 3
     WHEN 'Ph.D. students'   THEN 8
     WHEN 'Students'         THEN 7
     WHEN 'Other'            THEN 9
     ELSE   10
  END
```

Comment: While this will work in the given Case, it is a *terrible* Idea to couple the Query itself to data values. You would Need to modify the query everytime another value is added. And if you want to have another one on Position 1, you Need to Change 10 values.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>As it is currently implemented, you cannot order by in such a way that Scientific Staff is first, because doing an Oder By sorts it in order of the item in question (in your case, alphabetically it appears by role).</strike>

Now, the easy solution to this is to build out a sort priority table with those values in it, assign a numeric priority, then sort by the priority.  Let me explain that a little better because it can be confusing:

You make a second table, listing each of these roles, and in a second column give those roles a priority that they will be displayed by.

TABLE:
Role  | Priority

Scientific Staff |  1

Ph.D Students | 2

Other | 3
(etc)

You can then do something like this (pseudo-MySQL):

```
 select members.role from members
 inner join priority
 on members.role = priority.role
 order by priority.priority
```

that will give you the role field from the members table, ordered by the priority you set on the priority table.  Since it is an inner join, anyone without a role will not display.

Comment: "'you cannot order by in such a way that Scientific Staff is first'" - that is incorrect. See the most upvoted answer on  [Mysql order by specific ID values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8322898/761793)

Comment: I stand corrected.  I still feel my way is cleaner and a better implementation, though.