# MySQL PHP - SELECT WHERE based on a different position

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

Is it possible to sort data based on an order value set on a certaid IDs?

I want to make the following:

```
    ID - Position
    1  - 3rd
    2  - 4th
    3  - 5th
    4  - 6th
    10 - 7th
    11 - 8th
    12 - 9th
    13 - 10th
    14 - 11th
    83 - 2nd
    84 - 1st
```

I’ve been trying to implement this one, but it doesn’t generate the correct order:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,81,82) ORDER BY id = 3 DESC, id = 4 DESC, id = 5 DESC, id = 6 DESC, id = 7 DESC, id = 8 DESC, id = 9 DESC, id = 1 DESC, id = 2 DESC
```

If I was unclear, please ask me for more info. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want to order them by Position?

Comment: Why are you storing position with suffix? You can store just the integer value for position and order by that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use `order by FIELD` , below is an example you can modify the way you want.

```
SELECT * FROM 
table_name 
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,81,82)
order by FIELD(id,3,4,5,1,2,6,7,81,82)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field

Comment: According to his table this is the incorrect order and missing at least the number 84.

Comment: It was just an example I provided with the document link, a little document lookup and self try would solve the issue.

Comment: I understand. I was thinking he might think that the `ORDER BY FIELD` would return in a reverse order. Since he wanted his largest number to return first and you have a large number returning last...

Comment: In your screen-shot you have a question number and I suppose u store that in DB as well and if so why not sort by that number ? Since this way you need to know the order before sorting it.

Comment: yes.. that's what I did.. but I dont know how can I use that as a position for my sorting..

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,81,82) ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(position, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(position) - 2) as unsigned)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is sufficient you dont need to add anything in this.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,81,82) ORDER BY id DESC
```

or you can use, if want in particular sequence of ID,

```
SELECT * FROM  table_name  WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,81,82) order by FIELD(id,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2)
```

or you can use [ORDER BY CASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322849/mysql-order-by-specific-id-values)

Comment: This would put `82` first, `81` second, but then `7` in third. This is incorrect. The order should go `84, 83, 1...`

Comment: 84,83,1,2,3,4,10,11,12,13,14

Comment: you can set whatever order you want.... at this point you need to use your common sense.