# MYSQL Order By in a specific order

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to order a column in a specific way. Values are Urgent, Critical, Caution. 
Order I need it to is Critical, Urgent, Caution. 
"Order by Case when" does work in my database but seem that I might be missing or writing it incorrectly.

column name "Status" 
Values to order by specific way : Critical, Urgent, Caution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql order by specific ID values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322849/mysql-order-by-specific-id-values)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `order by field`

```
order by field(Status,'Critical','Urgent','Caution');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and I tried it and did not work. The "Status" is a label from a String formula I have. Dont know if that woudl help on narrowing down the script that I would need.

Comment: not sure I understand that is't it status is the column name of the table ?

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, thanks!  Exactly what I was looking for.