# Ordering by a value that is not in the database where selecting from

Tags: php

how would i go about ordering by a value that is not in the table where i am selecting from, in this instance the value $count1 is not in the table search.

count has the same identifying id as that of the thing it is being reffered to in the other table, this is where count1 is grabbed

```
$q = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(rating) FROM ratings WHERE id='$id' AND rating = 'd'");
$q->execute();
$count1 = $q->fetchColumn();

$query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE title LIKE '$each' ORDER BY '$count1'"
$query = $db->prepare($query);
$query->execute();
```

that is from ratings, how would i go about ordering the entries like that, so that they are based off the number of count1 and are decided, i might have to implement something like

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE title LIKE '$each' AND id = '$id' ORDER BY '$count1'"
$query = $db->prepare($query);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: thanks so much i will try that christian

Comment: use a nested query like "select title, (select COUNT(rating) from ratings where id='$id' and rating = 'd'") where title LIKE c=$each" then using the 2 columns compare and sort the array of results.

Comment: btw, what is the table "Search" for? did you already normalize your tables?

Comment: search is for the info that is provided with each 'search' so like description, link, etc

Answer (score 0):

Possible Duplicate: [Mysql order by specific ID values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322849/mysql-order-by-specific-id-values)

Same thing here, you'll just output your `$count1`as a comma separated string and add it in the SQL query as `ORDER BY FIELD(COUNT,___comma_sep_string___)`

Answer (score 0):

`ratings` is a table, not a database. You can join tables or use subqueries to get the desired result, without having to make multiple queries.

You haven't described how the `FOREIGN_KEY` is set up in the `ratings` table, but assuming you have something `ratings.search_id`, this should work:

```sql
SELECT search.*, (SELECT COUNT(rating) 
    FROM ratings 
    WHERE ratings.search_id = search.id 
    AND rating = 'd'
  ) AS rating_count 
FROM search 
WHERE title LIKE '$each'
ORDER BY rating_count
```