# How to retrieve specific rows from an arrow by row IDs in Cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

The below cakephp line brings back highest 3 car_ids from my database

```
$cars = $this->car->find('all',array('limit' => 3, 'order' => array('car.id' => 'desc')));
```

I want to be specific which 3 cars I need to pull using the below values:

```
car_id={3,7,10};
```

What is the right command for that?

Comment: what cakephp version?

Comment: make sure that " car.id " is correct

Comment: `car.id`  may be `car_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an `IN` condition in your query.

In MySQL this would look like:-

```
WHERE car.id IN (3, 7, 10)
```

In CakePHP 2.x you do that like this:-

```
$cars = $this->car->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'car.id' => array(3, 7, 10) // This is the `IN` condition
    ),
    'limit' => 3, 
    'order' => array('car.id' => 'desc')
));
```

CakePHP will automatically infer that you want to use `IN` as the value in the condition is an array.

In CakePHP 3.x we need to [tell CakePHP to use `IN`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#automatically-creating-in-clauses) so that it will cast the condition value to an array (otherwise you may get errors if the conditions value isn't what Cake is expecting):-

```
$cars = $this->car->find()
      ->where(['id IN' => [3, 7, 10]]);
      ->limit(3)
      ->order(['id' => 'DESC']);
```

Comment: Yes, this how it was fixed.

Comment: But now the order is asc or desc based on the car Id, I want to show the cars based on exact order. for example the array is { 3,10,7} I want to show 3 then 10 then 7, now desc shows 10 then 7 then 3, I want the order in the array to be followed. how is that?

Comment: @Dani see the accepted answer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322849/mysql-order-by-specific-id-values.

Comment: So how can use that SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(ID,1,5,4,3) with cakephp code above?

Comment: You can use `->order('FIELD(ID,1,5,4,3)')` in your query. If that doesn't work for you I suggest you start a new question relating to this so that it will be easier for people to help you. Comments aren't the place for asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

All you need just use a find method and after that use some conditions to get the values of rows you want.

I use OR in your car_id, cause i think you want to get all the rows which has the `car_id`'s.

**Your Updated Query:**

```
$cars = $this->car->find()
          ->where(['OR' => [['car_id' => 3], ['car_id' => 7], ['car_id' => 10]]])
          ->limit(3)->order(['car_id' => 'DESC']);
```

I think you may get helped. 
for more about CakePHP Query [see more](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this find query its work for you....its return data car_id with 3,7,10..

```
$cars = $this->Car->find('all',array("conditions"=>array("car_id IN"=>  [3,7,10] ),"order"=>"Car.car_id DESC"));
```

Comment: It not necessary to type `IN` , `"conditions" => array("car_id" => array(3, 7, 10))` will works the same.

Answer (score -2):

try this

car.id or car_id whatever your field name is for id

```
$car = $this->car->query('select * from tablename where car.id IN ("3","7","10")');
```