# How to Order related products by Product ID in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I've installed a plugin to allow me to add and customise the related products on a product page - [WooCommerce Custom Related Products](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/woo-custom-related-products/).

The plugin stores the related ID(s) in the `post_meta` table:

`meta_key` => *_wcrp_related_ids* 
`meta_values` => *a:3:{i:0;s:3:"159";i:1;s:3:"158";i:2;s:3:"244";}*

I would like to order the related products based on the order they are stored  e.g. 159, 158, 244.

I've been able to order the related products by the product id using the following code. But I'm not sure how I can modify to sort this by the `meta_values`.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_output_related_products_args', 'jk_related_products_args');

function jk_related_products_args($args)
{
    $args['orderby'] = 'id'; // This works
    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the WP_Query documentation. You should find what you need to order by custom meta.

Answer (score 0):

> As you are looking for [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8322898/5019802), WordPress has this
>   feature, you need to pass **`post__in`** in `orderby`.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_output_related_products_args', 'wh_related_products_args');

function wh_related_products_args($args)
{
    global $post;
    $related = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wcrp_related_ids', true); //replace it with your metakey
    //if a product do not have any realted product then don't alter order by
    if ($related)
    {
        $args['orderby'] = 'post__in';
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Reference: [Order by & include array by specific post ids](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/98118/103815)

*Code goes in `functions.php` file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**Code is tested and works.**

Hope this helps!