# Find records with ID in array of IDS and keep the order of records matching that of IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have an array of IDs:

```
array_of_ids = [5, 14, 2, 20]
```

I want to find all records of a class `Klass` that have an ID in the array, and keep the order they appear in the array.

```
Klass.where(id: array_of_ids)
```

returns the correct array, but it is unordered. Is there any way to keep the original order in the array? I can't simply use the `order` method because it is not an attribute but a method call. I also need to keep it as an active record relation.

Comment: from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322849/mysql-order-by-specific-id-values you could do `Klass.where(id: arr).order("FIELD(id,#{arr.join(',')}")` (if using MySQL)

Comment: Postgres? MySQL?

Comment: Might help - Postgres - Trying to get the above answer to fit as we speak

Comment: Thank you - add that as an answer please and I'll accept(I really did google before posting..)

Comment: it seems that PostgreSQL offers a similar function called `array_position`: `ORDER BY array_position(ARRAY[3, 1, 2], id);` (seen here: https://gist.github.com/cpjolicoeur/3590737). In your case, a simple `order("array_position(ARRAY[#{ids.join(',')], id)")` should do the trick

Comment: wow that seems even easier - am taking a look now thanks...
It's amazing how much new information can be gleaned from posts closed by admins...

Comment: While admin closed, it was a rails question with postgres answers. Had similar problem with sqlite3. `Klass.find([5, 14, 2, 20])` retained the order, where `Klass.where(id:[5, 14, 2, 20])` sorted it by id. On a Postgres application, both seemed to retain the order. Forgot that you can use find with an array of ids.