# arrange selected values in order mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 7 mysql records with five values `accepted = '1'`and two`accepted = '0'
user_id`value for `accepted = '1'`is`(6, 5, 4, 2, 1)`and for `accepted = '0' is (7, 3).`I have a variable`$uid` for which the values (6, 5, 4, 2, 1) must be organized in values by order `(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)` so in all link fields where is $uid value changes in order (1, 2, 3, 4, 5). I tried something like this. I need it to be like this.

```
    <a href="readmore.php?page=<?php echo 1; ?>"> More</a>
    <a href="readmore.php?page=<?php echo 2; ?>"> More</a>
    <a href="readmore.php?page=<?php echo 3; ?>"> More</a>
    <a href="readmore.php?page=<?php echo 4; ?>"> More</a>
    <a href="readmore.php?page=<?php echo 5; ?>"> More</a>
```

The code is like this:

```
    <a href="readmore.php?page=<?php echo $uid; ?>"> More</a>

    SET @user_id=0;

    SELECT @user_id:=@user_id+1 AS user_id,username,COUNT(*) as id_count FROM test
     GROUP BY username ORDER BY test DESC;

    SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (5,4,3,1,6) ORDER BY FIELD(id, 5,4,3,1,6);
```

Comment: you have error  ?? . . show the error message .. wrong result show your actula result and the expcted  result  ..

Comment: Code does not have an error, but it don't work as planned.

Comment: `select * from table where acepted=1 order by id desc`

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in this link here posted by Bjoern.

[Mysql order by specific ID values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322849/mysql-order-by-specific-id-values)

```
    CREATE TABLE `new_order` (
      `my_order` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `my_number` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`my_order`),
    UNIQUE KEY `my_number` (`my_number`)
    ) ENGINE=INNODB;

    This table will now be used to define your own order mechanism. 
    Add your values in there:

    my_order | my_number
    ---------+----------
      1 |         1
      2 |         5
      3 |         4
      4 |         3

    ...and then modify your SQL statement while joining this new table.

    SELECT *
    FROM your_table AS T1
    INNER JOIN new_order AS T2 on T1.id = T2.my_number
    WHERE ....whatever...
    ORDER BY T2.my_order;
```