# How I can call `Video.where(id: [1, 1])` and get two record in active record relationship?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have next ids - `video_ids: [1, 8, 2, 8, 3, 8]`. So, each second record must be with id 8.
When I make `Video.where(id: [1, 8, 2, 8, 3, 8]).ids` I have `[1, 8, 2, 3, 4]. So, active record find record with id 8 only one.

I would like after `Video.where(id: [1, 8, 2, 8, 3, 8])` have =>
`[<Video id: 1>, <Video id: 8>, <Video id: 2>, <Video id: 8>, <Video id: 3>, <Video id: 8>]`

What can be done to do this?

Comment: Do you need a Video::ActiveRecord_Relation or an Array?

Comment: Video::ActiveRecord_Relation

Comment: `Video.where(id: [1, 8, 2, 8, 3, 8])` translates to `WHERE videos.id IN (1, 8, 2, 8, 3, 8)` in SQL. It does not in ANY way give you the records in that specific order or cause duplicates in any db I know of. The order depends entirely on the order clause (or the dbs default order).

Comment: I think the problem is not the order, but the total of records that's not the same as the input for the IN clause @max.

Comment: @SebastianPalma I think the problem is either completely unrealistic expectations or an X&Y question. If you want to pull records in a specific order like that you would need to use `ORDER BY FIELD(id, 1, 8, 2, 8, 3, 8)` on MySQL or a case statement in Postgres. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322849/mysql-order-by-specific-id-values https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309624/simulating-mysqls-order-by-field-in-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

Edit: OP asked for an activerecord object so this woudn't work for him

You could map the video_ids array with the videos found, as ActiveRecord will return only one record per id.

```
def video_playlist(ids)
  videos = Video.where(id: ids)
  ids.map { |id| videos.detect { |video| video.id == id } }
end
```

and use the method

```
video_playlist(video_ids)
```

Comment: That returns an array.

Comment: Oh.. the comments must have happened while i was testing and trying.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to fetch duplicate records in an ActiveRecord::Relation object. If you know only the odd records are going to have variable ids and even records are always going to have a fix id, there is no need to fetch the fix id records along with other records. You can simply fetch `Video.where(id: [1, 2, 3])` together and fetch `Video.find(8)` in a separate query and write your logic based on this.