# How to order by from specific value in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

**Scenario:** I am making a medical report where I need the latest test result plus two past results (if the customer has taken the test in the past).

Consider this db:

```
id | patient_id | test_id | value
 1 |     3      |   5     |  10
 2 |     6      |   8     |  14
 3 |     3      |   5     |  12
 4 |     9      |   3     |  18
 5 |     3      |   10    |  4
 6 |     4      |   15    |  10
 7 |     3      |   5     |  19
 8 |     3      |   5     |  29
```

So if the patient comes and asks for the report **[row = 7]**, I need to show results of the past two records **[row = 3 and row = 1]** having the same patient_id and test_id.

What I have tried:

```
 $records = mysqli_query($con, "select * from value_based_result where patient_id='$ptid' and test_id='$testid' order by (id='$id') DESC, id  limit 3 ") or die(mysqli_error());
 while($record=mysqli_fetch_array($records)){ 
       echo $record['value'];                     
 }
```

Now the issue is, this query is not starting ordering by from current (id=7). It is just bringing (id=7) result to the top in query. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but maybe this thread is of any help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322849/mysql-order-by-specific-id-values

Comment: And see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound/executed queries

Comment: And simply id <= 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You include the id in the `order by`, but you need to use this as part of the `where` clause to give a starting point.  Assuming that 7 is the last one you want to fetch and all others will be less than that...

```
select * 
    from value_based_result 
    where patient_id=? 
        and test_id=?
        and id <= ?
    order by id desc  
    limit 3
```

You need to also look into how to use prepared statements - [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

As well as how to work with errors - [mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param)

Answer (score 0):

The `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function comes in handy here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY patient_id, test_id
                                 ORDER BY id DESC) rn
    FROM value_based_result
    WHERE id <= 7
)

SELECT id, patient_id, test_id, value
FROM cte
WHERE
    (patient_id, test_id) IN (SELECT patient_id, test_id
                              FROM value_based_result
                              WHERE id = 7) AND
    rn <= 3
ORDER BY
    id DESC;
```

### Demo