# How to get results in a custom order?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

Instead of `ASC` or `DESC`, I want my query results to be in a specific, custom order.

For example, instead of A, B, C, D..., what if I wanted my results in, P, A, L, H...?

I have tried using `case` but not successfully

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
ORDER BY case country
when 'P' then 1 …
```

E.g., here, I'm trying to create a custom order on the `Country` column:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL ORDER BY \[custom SET field value\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025675/mysql-order-by-custom-set-field-value)

Comment: There is no country called P. Are you looking for countries starting with that letter?

Comment: doesnt work.. same mistake

Comment: then consider 'Mexico' 'France'

Answer (score 156):

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
ORDER BY case when country = 'P' then 1
              when country = 'A' then 2
              when country = 'L' then 3
              when country = 'H' then 4
              else 5
         end asc
```

Comment: nt the exact result.... i am sorting by country 'Mexico' then 'France'..

Comment: @mhdnoufel: You should add example data and expected output to your question. This is all very unclear.

Comment: @juergend after the query ,,, i am getting the wrong result

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BvoCT.png This is what i want , u can see the wrong result

Comment: @mhdnoufel - So how do you want countries that are neither Mexico nor France sorted?

Comment: @MartinSmith i want mexioxo first france second in the result

Comment: @mhdnoufel - So add an `ELSE 3` into the `CASE`. You might also want to add `country` in as a secondary sort column.

Comment: code please. @MartinSmith i have tried all

Comment: @mhdnoufel: You could add a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) to your querstion with all the necessary example data. Then we can fix your issue.