# SQL Custom Sort By

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Let's say I have this in a column:

```
'a'
'b'
'c'
'd'
'e'
```

I want the data to be sorted and looked like this:

```
'a'
'b'
'd'
'e'
'c'
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Add a new column with order number which generating by your rules. No other method.

Comment: What is the logic for this ordering?  See the above comment as well.

Comment: I have some data where for nothing other than cosmetic purposes, I wanted one particular row above every other row, that was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select letter
from letters
order by
   case letter
     when 'a' then 0
     when 'b' then 1
     when 'd' then 2
     when 'e' then 3
     when 'c' then 4
   end
```

Comment: This is just the ans from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196475/custom-order-by-in-sql-server-for-eg-p-a-l-h-not-asc-or-desc.

Answer (score 2):

An other way around using **`CASE`** statement is,

**Query**

```
select [column_name] 
from [your_table_name]
order by 
  case [column_name] 
  when 'c' then 2 
  else 1 end, 
[column_name];
```

**[Find a demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/897931/sql-custom-sort-by)**