# MySQL GROUP BY with ORDER BY using specific words

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm having a trouble on how to get the ready status to show when there are multiple status on that id..

my database:

```
  ProjID   |  Status
    1         Ready
    2         Done
    1         Ongoing
    3         Done
    2         Ongoing
    1         Done
```

Expected output:

```
  ProjID   |  Status
    1         Ready
    2         Ongoing
    3         Done
```

when there is a Ready status on that ProjID Ready should appear but when there is no ready status ongoing status would appear but when there is also no ongoing status Done status would appear... the order is Ready,Ongoing,Done

I tried this

```
SELECT DISTINCT (projectID),Status FROM projStatus 
GROUP BY projectID 
ORDER BY FIELD(Status, 'Ready','Ongoing','Done' )
```

Comment: This question answers a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025675/mysql-order-by-custom-set-field-value

Comment: You are sorting by A-Z of the field of `Status`

Comment: @Keeper That problem has no distinct/group by used its just sorting... my problem is when I used the distinct/group by function the order by is not working I mean the done status is showing but the ready status should be appearing not the done status for that id

Comment: Then you need to do a nested query: first group by then order by. If you need an example I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query gives the expected output:

```
SELECT  projectID, max( Status ) Status
FROM projStatus 
GROUP BY projectID
```

demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdc1d8/4

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment here's the nested query:

```
SELECT projectID, Status
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT (projectID),Status 
  FROM projStatus 
  GROUP BY projectID 
) AS t
ORDER BY CASE Status
           WHEN 'Ready' THEN 1
           WHEN 'Ongoing' THEN 2
           WHEN 'Done' THEN 3
         END
```