# How to ORDER BY specific values in a SET when field has multiple values

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing names of personnel and their ranks.  Rank is a SET.  Each individual may have one or more values for Rank (the Asst. Chief might also be an Instructor, for example).

The desired result is a list of personnel sorted by top rank down, so Chief, Asst. Chief, Captain, etc.

I'm sorting the results by specific values in the set, which works *almost* as I expect it to.  The hangup is when a row has multiple values in the set, it does not sort them.

I started here: [MySQL ORDER BY [custom SET field value]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025675/mysql-order-by-custom-set-field-value)

This would work perfectly if all of the fields had only one single value.

Source data looks like this:

```
id  Name    Rank
1   Alex    Member
2   Mary    Chief
3   Sally   Instructor
4   Joe     Assistant Chief,Instructor
5   Jim     Captain
6   Bill    Member
7   Evan    Lieutenant,Instructor
```

And my query:

```
SELECT * FROM Members 
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(Rank, 'Chief,Assistant Chief,Captain,Lieutenant,Instructor,Member');
```

The desired result is:

```
id  name    rank
2   Mary    Chief
4   Joe     Assistant Chief,Instructor
5   Jim     Captain
7   Evan    Lieutenant,Instructor
3   Sally   Instructor
1   Alex    Member
6   Bill    Member
```

The actual result looks like:

```
id  name    rank
4   Joe     Assistant Chief,Instructor
7   Evan    Lieutenant,Instructor
2   Mary    Chief
5   Jim     Captain
3   Sally   Instructor
1   Alex    Member
6   Bill    Member
```

The rows where Rank has two values float up to the top of the search results.
I know it's probably something simple I'm missing -- what am I doing wrong?

Comment: A more logical table layout would be to move your rank column as title, then put an integer in the rank column with the "rank" you are looking for that you can sort with.
Also seems you should have a one to many relationship for the ranks since it looks like you are comma separating them which is a no no.

Answer (score 0):

I went with an ORDER BY CASE instead.

```
SELECT * FROM Members 
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN FIND_IN_SET('Chief', rank) THEN 1 
    WHEN FIND_IN_SET('Assistant Chief',rank) THEN 2 
    WHEN FIND_IN_SET('Captain',rank) THEN 3
    WHEN FIND_IN_SET('Lieutenant',rank) THEN 4
    WHEN FIND_IN_SET('Instructor',rank) THEN 5
    WHEN FIND_IN_SET('Member',rank) THEN 6
ELSE 7
END
```

This query produces the desired result.

Comment: Never ideal ordering by strings.